# How to accomplish 3 horizontal line menu in fxml

Tags: menu, javafx, overlay, fxml

I want to create menu like "Firefox (Three horizontal line - top right side) Menu". I don't know how to create this line of overlay menu in FXML. Have anybody any idea about this?

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example to give you a hint, further improvements and modifications are up to you:

```
@Override
public void start( final Stage primaryStage )
{
    Line l1 = new Line( 0.5, 0, 15.5, 0 );
    l1.setStrokeWidth( 2 );
    Line l2 = new Line( 0.5, 5, 15.5, 5 );
    l2.setStrokeWidth( 2 );
    Line l3 = new Line( 0.5, 10, 15.5, 10 );
    l3.setStrokeWidth( 2 );

    MenuButton m = new MenuButton();
    m.setGraphic( new Group( l1, l2, l3 ) );
    m.getItems().addAll( new MenuItem( "Settings" ), new MenuItem( "About" ) );

    Platform.runLater(() ->
    {
        // hide the arrow of menuButton
        m.lookup( ".arrow" ).setStyle( "-fx-background-insets: 0; -fx-padding: 0; -fx-shape: null;" );
        // hide the arraw-button pane, to remove unnecessary padding
        m.lookup( ".arrow-button" ).setStyle( "-fx-padding: 0" );
    });

    final Scene scene = new Scene( new Group( m ), 400, 300 );
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

The lines are put into MenuButton's graphic property. Since menubutton has an triangle arrow, we need to hide it by looking it up.

Alternatively, instead of using `Line` you can put a SVG image (String) to shape property of the button.

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I wanted. I will in-corporate my changes to it.